# Running unix checksum command in Python

Tags: python, unix, checksum

Is there anyway we can run below unix command in Python.

```
csum -h SHA1 <filename>
```

The checksum produced in python would be stored and supposed to match with the checksum produced by unix command in destination server.
I know we can produce checksum through python itself.
But I was not sure if this would match unix checksum produced on destination server.
So I was thinking if there is anyway we run the same command on both servers to ensure there is no mismatch because of unix and python

Comment: Use the same algoritm (sha1 on that case): https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
import commands 
print commands.getstatusoutput('csum -h SHA1 foobar')
(0, 'YOURCHECKSUM')
```

be aware that `commands` is deprecated in python 3